# iriscouch basic authentication not working

Tags: couchdb

I have only 1 server admin on my iriscouch setup.

I can successfully log by cookie auth

```
> POST https://myserv.iriscouch.com/_session
      name=username&password=password

{"ok":true,"name":null,"roles":["_admin"]}
```

But basic auth doesn't works

```
> PUT https://username:password@myserv.iriscouch.com/mynewdb

{"error":"unauthorized","reason":"You are not a server admin."}
```

I don't know if it's an iriscouch or a couchdb config issue

Comment: Have you tried using the `Authorization` HTTP Header?

Answer (score 0):

As Dominic recommended in comments I have checked my client raw request and noticed the `Authorization` header wasn't generated properly